# BFS (Breadth First Search) Algorithm in Java -> Cannot implement bfs by not getting node's siblings

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I have a problem about getting all siblings from the main node and implementing the process n Breadth First Search algorithm written by Java.

How can I implement that?

I shared my code snippets shown below.

Here is my Node class shown below.

```
public class Node{
    Node(int data){
       this.data = data;
       this.left = null;
       this.right = null;
       this.visited = false;
    }
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    boolean visited;

    // getter and setter 
}
```

Here is the initilaization process shown below.

```
Node node1 = new Node(1);
Node node7 = new Node(7);
Node node9 = new Node(9);
Node node8 = new Node(8);
Node node2 = new Node(2);
Node node3 = new Node(3);
node1.left = node7;
node1.right = node9;
node7.right = node8;
node9.right = node3;
node9.left = node2;
```

Here is the method shown below.

```
public static void bfs(Node root){
        if (root == null){
            return;
        }
        
        Node temp; //a binary tree with a inner generic node class
        Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<>(); //can't instantiate a Queue since abstract, so use LLQueue
        
        queue.add(root);
        root.visited = true;
        while (!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            temp = queue.poll(); //remove the node from the queue
            
            // How can I get all siblings of the node like
            // for (Node sibling : temp.getSiblingNodes())
            // sibling.visited=true;
            // queue.add(sibling);
            
        }

        // get the result as a list
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to get the sibling of a node. If you push the *children* of the current node to the queue, you will guarantee that you pull them out of the queue in sibling order. The important thing here is that you visit a node when it is *pulled* from the queue, not when it is added to the queue.

So your function could be turned into this:

```
    public static List<Node> bfs(Node root){
        Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Node> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if (root == null){
            return result;
        }
        queue.add(root); // Don't visit this root node yet...
        while (!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            Node node = queue.poll();
            result.add(node); // Here we visit the node
            // Add the children of the visited node to the queue
            if (node.left != null) queue.add(node.left);
            if (node.right != null) queue.add(node.right);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The caller can do this:

```
    for (Node node : bfs(node1)) {
        System.out.println(node.data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Node` has a property `isVisited`, I assume that there could be cycles in the Graph.

The algorithm can be described in the following steps:

- Mark the `root` Node as visited and put it into the Queue.
- Then until the Queue is not empty, repeat:

  - Remove the Node (`current` Node) from the head of the Queue;
  - Check its `left` and `right` child-Nodes. If a child-Node exists (i.e. not `null`) and hasn't been visited yet, then add this node both into the Queue and resulting list of sibling-Nodes and set `isVisited` property of the child-Node to `true`.

That's how it might be implemented:

```
public static List<Node> bfs(Node root) {
    if (root == null) return Collections.emptyList();
    
    List<Node> siblings = new ArrayList<>();
    Queue<Node> queue = new ArrayDeque<>(); // performs better than LinkedList
    
    queue.add(root);
    // siblings.add(root); // uncomment this line ONLY if you need the root-Node to be present in the result
    root.visited = true;
    
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Node current = queue.poll();

        tryAdd(siblings, queue, current.left);
        tryAdd(siblings, queue, current.right);
    }
    return siblings;
}

public static void tryAdd(List<Node> siblings, Queue<Node> queue, Node next) {
    if (next != null && !next.isVisited()) {
        queue.add(next);
        siblings.add(next);
        next.setVisited(true);
    }
}
```

To avoid repeating the same actions for both `left` and `right` child-Nodes, I've created method `tryAdd()`.

We can alter its conditional logic by introducing a `Predicate` (*in this case condition is short and well readable, and this option is shown rather for education purposes*):

```
public static final Predicate<Node> IS_NULL_OR_VISITED =
    Predicate.<Node>isEqual(null).or(Node::isVisited);

public static void tryAdd(List<Node> siblings, Queue<Node> queue, Node next) {
    if (IS_NULL_OR_VISITED.test(next)) return;
    
    queue.add(next);
    siblings.add(next);
    next.setVisited(true);
}
```

Comment: I got 7 -> 9 -> 8 -> 2 -> 3 instead of 1 -> 7 -> 9 -> 8 -> 2 -> 3. Is it useful to add root value at the end of resultlist? How can I do that?

Comment: @S.N See the commented line `// siblings.add(root);` if you need the root to be present in the result - uncomment it (I was not sure on that point therefore posted it as comment out). *Is it useful to add root value at the end of resultlist* - at the **end** or at the **beginning** ? [**See both here**](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/ABd).